# How fill variable values in strings variable in angular 8/ javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

I have following string with variable

```
var data = "{

  title: {
      text: **title**
  }, 

  subtitle: {
      text: **subtitle**
  }
}"
```

and I have following data

```
data_to_be_fill = {
    "title": "My title",
    "subtitle": "My subtitle"
}
```

Now I want to replace `**title**` with "My title" and `**subtitle**` with "My subtitle"

Expected output should be

```
  "{

      title: {
          text: "My title"
      }, 

      subtitle: {
          text: "My subtitle"
      }
    }"
```

Is there any to do that in angular/java script?

Comment: Tried anything?

Comment: yes I tried something like this
```const name = "My title"
const greeting = `Hello ${name}````
but in this process I need to declare multiple variable I want this dynamic using my data dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the properties of `data_to_be_fill` object using `Object.keys` and then replace each of them by it's value.

Try like this:

```
Object.keys(this.data_to_be_fill).forEach(item => {
  this.data = this.data.replace(`**${item}**`, `"${this.data_to_be_fill[item]}"`);
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mnn2hh?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**